# Access the name of selectInput return value

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following shiny app.  The `choices` argument to `selectInput()` is a named vector, meaning that the user sees the names, and internally the values are used.  In the app below, the `textOutput` prints the value of the selected option.  How can I print the name instead?  `names(input$variable)` returns `NULL`.

```r
shinyApp(
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "variable",
      "Variable:",
      c(
        "Cylinders" = "cyl",
        "Transmission" = "am",
        "Gears" = "gear"
      )
    ),
    textOutput('name')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$name <- renderText({
      input$variable
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a "dictionary" for example.

```r
Names <- c("Cylinder", "Transmission", "Gears")
Values <- c("cyl", "am", "gear")
dict <- setNames(Names, Values)
```

then:

```r
dict[input$variable]
```

Comment: Is there a way to directly access the name?  This way looks like it forces me to store another variable with the names as the values.

Comment: @joshbrows No. You can also use these two vectors to make the `choices` list, so it's not bad. Otherwise use only the `choices` list, and use `which`.